# gulp uglify unclearify error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm using gulp uglify, and I'm getting an error.

this is my code:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var deleteLines = require('gulp-delete-lines');

// JS concat, strip debugging and minify
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  gulp.src(['./layout3/**/*.js','!./layout3/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(deleteLines({
      'filters': [/<script\s+type=["']text\/javascript["']\s+src=/i, /<script>/i]
    }))
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e);
         }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./layout2'));
});
```

I add print screen of the error:

[image]

I know that there is a problem in jquery.elevatezoom file, I can't find the problem.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

i got this error after update the 'gulp-uglify', in my case is the pipe was replaced by pump.

because the pump can show error detail, checkt this [why use pump](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/docs/why-use-pump/README.md#why-use-pump)

so, maybe you can try this:

```
var pump = require('pump'); //npm install it first

    gulp.task('cssmin', function (cb) {
      pump([
         gulp.src(['./layout3/**/*.js','!./layout3/**/*.min.js']),
         deleteLines({'filters': [/<script\s+type=["']text\/javascript["']\s+src=/i, /<script>/i]}),
         uglify().on('error', function(e){
             console.log(e);
           })
         gulp.dest('./layout2')
           ],
       cb
     );});
```

it works on my project now, hope it can help.